# ArrayIndexErrorException when inserting dynamically a JPanel into a TabbedPanel

Tags: java, swing, layout, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm trying to implement a JFrame with a JTabbedPane as main component (this is the only component of the JFrame). At the beginning, the tabbed panel should not contain any tab. Latter are added when an event occurs. Each the tab contains a JPanel with a BorderLayout. This is the piece of code where I get some problems. Effectively, when adding the tab, I get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException. I have identified the line of code where the error is produced, and it happens when I add the second element to the panel. Does someone know how to fix this error ? I tried to catch the error but it doesn't work. This the implementation I have right now :

This is the code of the main frame

```
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;

public class MyFrame extends JFrame {

    static JTabbedPane main;

    public MyFrame() {
        main = new JTabbedPane();
        this.add(main);
        this.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(600, 800));
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.pack();
    }

    public static JPanel addTab(String title) {
        MyPanel panel = new MyPanel();
        main.addTab(title, panel);
        return panel;
    }
}
```

This is the class of the panel inside a tabbed panel :

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneLayout;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class MyPanel extends JPanel {
    private JPanel scrollPanel;
    private JTextArea textArea;
    private JButton button;
    public MessageTo panel;

    public MyPanel() {

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(
                JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
                JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        scrollPane.setLayout(new ScrollPaneLayout());
        scrollPanel = new JPanel();
        scrollPane.setViewportView(scrollPanel);
        scrollPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(scrollPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        textArea = new JTextArea();
        Border roundedBorder = new LineBorder(Color.black, 1, true);
        textArea.setBorder(roundedBorder);

        button = new JButton("Send");
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 10, 0, 0));
        panel1.add(button);

        JPanel inner_panel = new JPanel();
        inner_panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        inner_panel.add(panel1, BorderLayout.EAST);
        inner_panel.add(textArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        inner_panel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));

        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.add(inner_panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH); // This line produces the error
    }
}
```

And this is the error I have :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI.tabForCoordinate(BasicTabbedPaneUI.java:1506)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI.setRolloverTab(BasicTabbedPaneUI.java:575)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI.access$2000(BasicTabbedPaneUI.java:54)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI$Handler.mouseEntered(BasicTabbedPaneUI.java:3626)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.trackMouseEnterExit(Container.java:4620)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4474)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:747)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:718)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:717)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Thank you !

EDIT :

This is the code you can use to test my code :

```
public class Main {

    public static MyFrame frame;

    public static void main(String[] args)   {

        frame = new MyFrame();
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                frame.addTab("Test");
            }
        }.start();
    }

}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).  Note that the code might almost be an MCVE, if it had only one `public` class (with the other copy/pasted into the end), imports and a `main(String[])` method to run it.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would declare `JTabbedPane main` as `static`. I hope you understand that this results in ALL MyFrame objects sharing this static object. Which means if it is modified in one place it will affect all others.  I just created this simple test class with main method and your code works as expected, I get 4 tabs. `public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  MyFrame x = new MyFrame();
  x.addTab("a");
  x.addTab("b");
  x.addTab("x");
  x.addTab("x");
 }`

Comment: Actually, I declare it static since I should only have one only one MyFrame object. In fact, the tab should be added dynamically by another thread this is why this is done in that way in my main function. This is weird because I don't get the error all the time.

Comment: Weird think, if I sleep the thread for 1 second for example, Then I add a tab, I never get an error any more.

Comment: You're modifying swing components outside the [event dispatch thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html). That can result in all sort of weird effects.

Comment: Thank you kiheru, this is cleaner in my mind. Is there a way to had event in this thread to be sure it will not produce weird effects ?

Comment: The short version is that if you need to access or create swing components from another thread, use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` (that executes the code in the EDT). For more complete explanation, read the other chapters of the tutorial I linked to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Kiheru suggest, by the modification of frame from another thread must be done in this way :

```
public class Main {

    public static MyFrame frame;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException,
            ExecutionException, UnknownHostException, IOException {

        frame = new MyFrame();
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        frame.addTab("Test");
                    }
                });
                try {
                    this.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        frame.addTab("Test2");
                    }
                });
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
   new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            frame.addTab("Test");
        }
    }.start();
```

with

```
frame.addTab("Test");
```

At the moment, you are trying to modify the GUI elements from another thread than the one where your `JFrame` is. It is possible that the code that adds tabs is reached before the program is finished with building the window, hence the error. [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) might be a good read.

Comment: I see but the frame must be updated by another thread (I only give you a small part of my whole implementation). The only solution I have is to declare the frame inside the non-main thread ?

Comment: The frame should be in the main thread. From any other thread you should call GUI-methods on objects that also are in the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

```
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
```

Pleas read about this here... https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/simple.html

```
    new SwingWorker() {
      @Override protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        return null;
      } 
      @Override protected void done() {
        //PUT HERE THE CODE
        frame.addTab("Test");
        frame.addTab("Test2");
      }
    }.execute();
```